# Decryption of encrypted ViewState

Tags: asp.net, .net, viewstate

Brief background: I have two-step login page, which after step 1 sends one-time code to user's email. I do not need this code anywhere except on step 2. I googled around and decided to store original code into Encrypted ViewState. So the question: is it security safe? is it possible to decrypt encrypted viewstate on client-side and get code from there? (of course, I mean truly encrypted viewstate, not just base64ed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its my understanding that ViewState is serialized into a base-64 encoded string using the MachineKey in machine.config.  In order for the client (I am guessing javascript) to decode it wouldn't you have to expose the MachineKey?  This would not be good at all.

Answer (score 1):

ViewState can be decoded:

Tool 1: [View State decoder](http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx)
Tool 2: [Http Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/)
Tool 3: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: These ones can decrypt even encrypted viewstates or only base64ed?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to decrypt anything given enough time and a sufficient sample set. ViewState is not exactly secure either. If you have information you don't want falling into a potential attacker's hands, you should absolutely leave it out of the ViewState.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't recommend it.
How would you cope if your user lost their internet connection after you email the onetime code but before they get to use it?

Comment: They will simply relogin and get another code. I do not see problem here. I'm scared that someone will bypass email verification.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting and decoding are two different things. 
Base64 decoding a Base64 encoded string isn't for security purposes.
Decrypting an Encrypted string requires the key.

You first encode, then encrypt.

Comment: Could you expand on this?